# Optimizing a query to avoid CXPacket wait type

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I am selecting some columns from a table, then matching these columns' fields with another table to retrieve some data. The code(with the indexes on respective tables) is as follows:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_#Table1
ON Table1(
             VarcharCol1
            ,VarcharCol2    
            ,VarcharCol3
            ,VarcharCol4
            ,NVarcharCol
         )

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_#Table3
ON Table3(
              date
            ,VarcharCol1
            ,VarcharCol2    
            ,VarcharCol3
            ,VarcharCol4
            ,NVarcharCol
            ,DecCol
         )

DECLARE CUR1 CURSOR
FOR SELECT   VarcharCol1
            ,VarcharCol2    
            ,VarcharCol3
            ,VarcharCol4
            ,SUM(IntCol) IntCol
            ,SUM(DecCol) DecCol
            ,NVarcharCol
    FROM Table1 WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
    WHERE date= @date
    AND IntCol IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY VarcharCol1,VarcharCol2,VarcharCol3,VarcharCol4,NVarcharCol
OPEN CUR1

FETCH NEXT FROM  CUR1
    INTO @VarcharCol1,@VarcharCol2,@VarcharCol3,@VarcharCol4,@IntCol,@DecCol,@NVarcharCol

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Table2
            SELECT TOP (@IntCol) *
            FROM Table3 a WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)
            WHERE date      = @date
            AND VarcharCol1 = @VarcharCol1
            AND VarcharCol2 = @VarcharCol2              
            AND VarcharCol3 = @VarcharCol3
            AND VarcharCol4 = ISNULL(@VarcharCol4,'')
            AND NVarcharCol = ISNULL(@NVarcharCol,NVarcharCol)
            ORDER BY DecCol DESC

    FETCH NEXT FROM  CUR1
    INTO @VarcharCol1,@VarcharCol2,@VarcharCol3,@VarcharCol4,@IntCol,@DecCol,@NVarcharCol
END

CLOSE CUR1
DEALLOCATE CUR1
```

Now, the query that is inserting data into Table2 from Table3 above is causing a CXPacket wait type. I have optimized and optimized and find myself befuddled now. Please help!

Comment: Why not just remove the cursor and change it to one set-based query instead?

Comment: CXPACKET waits are normal for a parallel query but excessive parallelism may be an indicator of the need for index and query tuning. Besides removing the cursor, have you indexed any of the columns in the `WHERE` clause? Add DDL to your question.

Comment: What evidence do you have that you need to remove CXPACKET waits? Just because there are CXPACKET waits does not mean they are a problem. Often they are just an indicator that parallelism is working.

Comment: @BrentOzar I have implemented the change that you recommended and subsequently, the query now executes in one fourth of the time that it took before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to rework your query and avoid using cursor. I believe this will improve performance.

Also maybe it will be useful for you: try to add `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` to your query. I don't know your SQL Server configuration, but you can play with this option.

Comment: How would maxdop 0 prevent parallelism?